# SQLite Cursor getColumnIndex() returning -16 even when column exists

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm storing a number of objects for my app in an SQLite Database. The class for these objects has a constructor that takes a Cursor object, passed in from the Database class. Example:

```
public MyClass(Cursor cursor) {
    this.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.KEY_ROWID));
    this.nickname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.KEY_NICKNAME));
```

...and so on.

However I've noticed that at random times I've been getting a crash when getColumnIndex for the ID column returns -16. (And if I comment out that line, whichever the first column I try to access is, it will also return -16). I've added some extra logging around it but it hasn't helped as it seems like the columns are fine:

```
public MyClass(Cursor cursor) {     
    Log.i("TEST", Column names are: " + Arrays.toString(cursor.getColumnNames()));
    Log.i("TEST", Making object, id column index is " + cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.KEY_ROWID));
```

Which prints:

```
Column names are: [_id, nickname...]
Making object, id column index is -16
```

So it sees like everything should be fine, anyone got any clue why everything could be getting so messed up while reading from the Cursor?

EDIT: Here's how I'm getting the cursor, this is a method in the database class:

```
public MyObject getMyObject(String id) {
    MyObject objectFound = null;
    String[] whereArgs = { id };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, getTableName(), null, WHERE_EQUALS, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //Should only return 1 entry from DB
        while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            objectFound = new MyObject(cursor);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    cursor.close();     
    return objectFound;     
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the cursor?

Comment: Edited original question with that method

Comment: It is impossibile! `getColumnIndex() returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist`. Maybe your database is corrupted!

Comment: And MyDatabase.KEY_ROWID is........and column in database is....... Fill the gap :-)

Comment: @Selvin in each case getColumnIndex() must return a greater then zero value (or -1)

Comment: @Selvin: public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id"; So it does work fine normally, this just happens at random (and causes a crash). Joseph82, you don't need to tell me this is bizarre! The actual contents of the database look fine when I print them.

Comment: @Joseph82 Youre right :-) remove while loop and moveToNext

Comment: @Selvin, tried that, still no luck :( CRASH: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -16 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Lol moveToFirst should do the trick.... What is the device. ... I have to be sure to not buy one since your code looks ok.... I see the only one possibility are you using another thread to modify the db at the same time?

Comment: @Catha You have to try to test it in debug mode

Comment: @Selvin, ha it's a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running 4.0.4, though I've also seen it on a Motorola Xoom too. But it's running fine on a Galaxy S3, and Sony Xperia Z, so who knows where the problem is.

Comment: @CathalComerford I've same issue, sometimes it return strange values as "4016", I only have 10 columns in my query. The only solution is to use hard-coded value. How do you solve this ?